# winapi - how to detect a mouse move over a context menu

Tags: winapi

I have created a custom context menu using MFT_OWNERDRAW flag and handling WM_MEASUREITEM and WM_DRAWITEM messages:

[image]

I would like to detect when a mouse cursor is over a color square in the context menu. It looks like that I can't subclass HMENU and receive WM_MOUSEMOVE event. How to detect a mouse move over a context menu ?

Comment: `TrackPopupMenu` runs an internal message loop. If you install a `WH_MSGFILTER` hook before calling it, then you can intercept the messages the menu's message loop will retrieve.

Comment: Just curious, what would you do with this mouse information if you could get it?

Comment: Then I can open a window which allow to choose a color (ChooseColor function). That color can be used to mark something in the application. The above example is a little bit simplified.

Comment: @Irbis Mouse moving on the color area opens a window may confuse users because the mouse maybe there unconsciously. I'm wondering if something like [Tooltips and Infotips](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/uxguide/ctrl-tooltips-and-infotips) are more suitable instead of an opened window?